# How to send mail when a reservation is done

Tags: php, html, email

I'm a new student of PHP language.

My problem is: I want to send a confirmation mail to the customer and the restaurant owner (firstly). But I don't understand everything in PHP currently.

[My PHP code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5TRY.jpg).

And my form HTML code:

```
<form action="../restau-php/reservationOK.php" id="reservationform" method="POST">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Votre nom et votre prénom</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Votre nom et votre prénom"
                                title="Entrez votre nom et votre prénom" required>
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail"
                                placeholder="Votre adresse mail" title="Entrez votre email s'il vous plaît" required>
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Téléphone</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone"
                                placeholder="Entrez votre numéro de téléphone" title="Entrez votre numéro de téléphone s'il vous plaît"
                                required>
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="guests">Invités</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="person" name="person"
                                placeholder="Combien serez-vous ?" title="Entrez le nombre d'invités s'il vous plaît" required>
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="timepicker">Heure</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="timepicker" name="time"
                                placeholder="Choisissez votre heure" title="Choissisez votre heure d'arrivée" required>
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                   
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="datepicker">Date de réservation</label>
                            <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker"
                                placeholder="Choisissez une date" title="Entrez la date de réservation s'il vous plaît" required>
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="reservation-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="js-reservation-btn">Réservez votre table</button>
                            <div id="js-reservation-result" data-success-msg="Votre réservation a bien été enregistré."
                                data-error-msg="Oups. Il semble qu'il y ait une erreur dans le formulaire !"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: ___But your PHP Code should be here___ (in the question) and NOT as a picture, thats no use to us if we want to copy/paste parts or all of it into an answer

Comment: Please add your code and explain what currently happens with it.

Comment: I tried to put it as code but it seemed to be disorganized

Comment: Use the formatting toolbar to mark your code correctly, or see [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to format it. Also, try to make sure the code you post is a [mcve] - we don't need to, and don't want to, read through your whole application.